# Cassandra CLI ANTLR issues

Tags: cassandra

When I start up Cassandra CLI with the host/ports all set up, whenever I try to type anything (even help or quit), it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognizerSharedState
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliLexer.<init>(CliLexer.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliCompiler.compileQuery(CliCompiler.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStatement(CliClient.java:198)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processStatementInteractive(CliMain.java:220)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.RecognizerSharedState
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

It looks like to me a problem with Antlr, but I don't have any experience in that area. I'm pretty sure my Cassandra ring is up and running without problems too. Anyone know what's up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running from a source checkout, a binary tarball, or a packaged installation? I suspect that the classpath isn't being set up properly or all of the dependencies haven't been fetch yet (if you're running from source).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason was that I wasn't using the newest version of antlr (3.2 as of right now). Thanks anyways!